# The principle of makom as it pertains to bentching

Tags: halacha, bentching, tractate-brachot, location

Gemara brachos records the dispute regarding one who forgets to make birkat hamazon. One shittah says you should return to the location he ate before making the bracha. How specifically does this parameter apply? Do you return to the same seat? The 4 Amos? The same room? Visual proximity (where you would be mitztaref to a zimun at your original location)?

How do we define the halachic principal of makom?

Comment: The Shulchan Aruch and its commentators debate this issue extensively. Is this a good question for Mi Yodeya?

Comment: By all means provide a synopsis and/or point to sources. Many questions here get quotes from mishnah berura and shulchan aruch. That doesn't make them bad questions. That there's debate proves it's worth discussing.